# Format string by CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

I want to show pound sign and the format 0.00 i.e £45.00, £4.10 . I am using the following statement:

```
<td style="text-align:center"><%# Convert.ToString(Convert.ToSingle(Eval("tourOurPrice")) / Convert.ToInt32(Eval("noOfTickets")), new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")) %></td>
```

But it is not working. What is the problem.

Can any one help me???

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use the [Currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) standard format string along with the [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) method that takes a format provider:

```
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", amount)
```

The CultureInfo can act as a format provider and will also get you the correct currency symbol for the culture.

Your example would then read (spaced for readability):

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <%# string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), 
                      "{0:C}", 
                      Convert.ToSingle(Eval("tourOurPrice")) 
                             / Convert.ToInt32(Eval("noOfTickets")))
    %>
</td>
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Your are applying a culture to a string, which I don't think will have any affect.

Comment: This is what I tried: string foo = String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", Convert.ToString(3.01));

Comment: @Joe: ah, I see what you're referring to now. I've updated my answer to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
<%# (Convert.ToSingle(Eval("tourOurPrice")) / Convert.ToInt32(Eval("noOfTickets"))).ToString("C", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specify exact currency format

```
String.Format(...CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}"....
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
<%# String.Format( new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:c}", Convert.ToSingle(Eval("tourOurPrice")) / Convert.ToInt32(Eval("noOfTickets")) %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an additional related answer to show how to use a cloned CultureInfo object in a string.Format() or StringBuffer.AppendFormat(). Instead of currency though, my need was to format the AM/PM designator for my employer's style guide. Here is what I did:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "a.m.";
culture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "p.m.";
....
var msg = new StringBuilder();
msg.AppendFormat(culture,"Last modified: {0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}", ad.DateModified);
```

You can do the same thing with string.Format():

```
string strMsg = string.Format(culture, "Last modified: {0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt}", ad.DateModified);
```