# Selecting different regional options changes result of the math operation in c#

Tags: c#, globalization, decimal-point, regional-settings

Im using Visual Studio 2010. My code has a strange behavior

With this code I can parse xml file.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("http://www.studiovincent.net/list.xml");
XElement resourcesElement = document.Root.Element("resources");
XElement resourceElementVincent = (from resourceElement in resourcesElement.Elements("resource")
                                           where resourceElement.Elements("field").Single(fieldElement => fieldElement.Attribute("name").Value == "name").Value == "Vincent"
                                           select resourceElement).Single();

decimal tasso = Math.Round(decimal.Parse(resourceElementVincent.Elements("field").Single(fieldElement => fieldElement.Attribute("name").Value == "age").Value) / Convert.ToInt64(1.00E+006), 6);


string gigi = Math.Round(41 * tasso, 4).ToString();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", gigi);
Console.ReadLine();
```

All work correctly, until I change regional options. If I select italian:

[image]

This is OUTPUT: **0,0013**

[image]

If I select United States in regional options, this is OUTPUT: **0.0000**

[image]

I dont know how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you purposely attempting to shorten it to four zeros? ie.e, `0000`?

It could be that there is a rounding issue somewhere, but it is cutting it off due to length of allowed output.  See if you can increase the length of the output, you might find "hidden" values that weren't being displayed before.  If that's the case, change the way the output is parsed for the respective region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimal.Parse(string)` uses the current system format; thus

```
decimal.Parse(resourceElementVincent.Elements("field")
       .Single(fieldElement => fieldElement.Attribute("name").Value == "age")
       .Value)
```

will return zero when Vincent's age is set to 0.27 and the current culture is Italian (where the [NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) is a comma).

However, you could use the `decimal.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` method instead, passing the `InvariantCulture` (where the NumberDecimalSeparator is a period):

```
decimal.Parse(resourceElementVincent.Elements("field")
       .Single(fieldElement => fieldElement.Attribute("name").Value == "age")
       .Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx).

Comment: ok thank for the info, but I dont understand if I set italian, I get this output:0,0013 and if I set USA I get this result: 0.0000

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the parsing of 1.00E+006 is dependent upon the current region.

Comment: are you right, 1.00E+006 is dependent upon the current region, thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is normal! European languages use decimal points as commas, and vice-versa.  If you want to use one or the other consistently, you can set a specific culture in conjunction with String.Format, as seen here:

[Format string by CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266093/format-string-by-cultureinfo)

Comment: ok but I would like that this code work in all regional options, I dont understant so I need add it. :(

Comment: His problem is not `,` vs `.`, he's quite literally getting different results.