# How to set the ConverterCulture at Xamarin Forms in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, converters, culture

I am using Xamarin Forms (XAML) at a project where I need to show a price. To show the correctly formatted price I am using `StringFormat` like:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}'}"/>
```

The result depends on the culture of the device the app is running (German: €, American: $, ...). My goal is always to use the German culture. Based on [adrianbanks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266093/format-string-by-cultureinfo) this is possible in WPF. I tried to use this approach like

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='de-DE'}"/>
```

but the result is the following `XamlParseException`:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "CultureInfo": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

It seems like Xamarin Forms does not provide this. I searched a lot but found no solution how to set the culture of the formatter in XAML. Is there a wy to solve my problem **without implementing my own converter**?

Comment: have you tried setting `xml:lang="de-DE"` at the top level? for example if you use an `UserControl` `<UserControl xml:lang="de-DE"/>`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion @XAMIMAX but its not working.

Comment: `<UserControl x:Class="SO_app.ForSergman"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
             xml:lang="en-GB"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">` I meant in the actual User Control.

Comment: Yeah I tried it like this

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I used a workaround setting the culture of the whole application like `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");`. Unfortunately this is just a dirty workaround since I found no better way.

Comment: My Xamarin.Forms project doesn't even give me the CultureConverter attribute of the Binding markup extension.

Comment: Filled an issue related to this [Implement ConverterCulture for bindings #12181](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12181)