# Application Running in Docker Container having a different CultureInfo in DotNet Core when compared to Dot Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, docker, .net-core

Im migrating my application from Dot Net Framework to Containerised Dot Net Core 6.
Running this code to print a Negative Currency Value.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:c}", -495));
```

In Dot-Net Framework and Dot-net core In Windows the Behaviour is ($495) and in Dot-Net Core container it is displayed as -$495. I cannot hard code in my application but I was hoping to making changes in the locale of the docker container. Is there any ways to achieve this.

Comment: What image are you using?

Comment: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try set the current thread with the desired culture

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUiCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Or directly the string format method:

[Format string by CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266093/format-string-by-cultureinfo)